# Background image isn't showing up?

Tags: html, css, image

Okay, so I've linked an image to a div section for a website. However, the image will not show up once uploaded to the server. I've double checked my CSS file, and nothing seems amiss, but perhaps I'm missing something.

CSS:

```
div{
    background-image: url(/images/medical-marijuana-background.jpg);
    background-repeat: space;
    border: solid #0D8200 .15em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="about">
<h2> About this website</h2>
<p>This page is dedicated to educating those who are interested in the medical benefits of marijuana as a medical option, and also to refute some of the misinformation about cannabis. As a  medical option, or even in general terms, cannabis is drastically under-researched. In fact in July of 2015 eight senators not only indicated that there is a lack of research on marijuana as a medical option, but also asked the Obama administration what is being done to further advance the reasearch.(<em> Medical marijuana research </em>, 2015) Ultimately, the purpose of this site is to not just educate, but also raise awareness. Raise awareness of the benefits of cannabis, raise awareness of the need to conduct more research/studies on cannabis as a medical option, and also give some history about cannabis.
</p>
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Works for me. So the question then becomes, are you really accessing the image? Can you access http://yoursite.com/image/medical...

Comment: Background-repeat:space isn't supported by most browsers.

Comment: Also check your DOM explorer and ensure that your image is actually being loaded and not 404ing.

Comment: @rob i am unsure how to use yoursite.com/etc. I attempted to type in http://www.yoursite.com/images/medical-marijuana-background.jpg and it says "403 Forbidden
Request forbidden by administrative rules."

Comment: you probably need to replace "yoursite.com" with your site xD

Comment: You Missing the height weight see my answer

Comment: ahem... right. I didn't exactly think that one through. Thanks for the tip, and when fixing my mistake, I can pull up the image.

Comment: @jdsfighter Do you by chance have a link to a good tutorial on how to use the DOM explorer for Firefox? I am still very new to coding for websites, and I've never used the DOM before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off your CSS does not match your HTML. In your HTML you set div id="about". so to call it in your CSS you have to write #about instead of "div", like so:

```
#about {
background-image: url(/images/medical-marijuana-background.jpg);
background-repeat: space;
border: solid #0D8200 .15em;
}
```

Second, you are calling your image improperly. if your .html file is in the same directory as your image, you call the image like so:

```
url(input.jpg)
```

If the image is in a subfolder called images one level below your .html, then you call it like this:

```
url(images/input.jpg)
```

Finally if your image is actually one level ABOVE your .html, and in a subfolder called images, you would call it like this:

```
url(../images/input.jpg)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong, per se - but not optimal. That css would make ANY <div> have that background. If there was more than one div (like in a real world situation), you're completely right though.

Comment: Thanks for the critique, but I never said his div was wrong? I stated that his CSS did not match his HTML. I said his image call was wrong. But even then its still not wrong, just improper. Let me edit that last bit.

Comment: AHA! This fixed my problem! Thank you! I can't believe that I was overlooking the "/" before images. Thank you again. Also, as a side note, I wasn't thinking far enough ahead when I was using the "div" element in my CSS as on the other pages of the site I am coding do use more DIV elements, and some of them I do not want to have the same background.

Comment: That's what your whole first paragraph said @Fearium. Like I said, you aren't wrong, but that's why it's good we both explained to OP the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `width` and a `height` of the background image for it to display properly.

```
div{
    background-image: url(images/medical-marijuana-background.jpg);
     width:xxpx;
     height:xxpx;
    border: solid #0D8200 .15em;
}
```

**If you want to repeat**

```
div{
    background-image: url(images/medical-marijuana-background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y; /* for vertical repeat */
    background-repeat: repeat-x; /* for horizontal repeat */
    height:xxpx;
    border: solid #0D8200 .15em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `:before` or `:after` selector in `css`.

```
 div
{
  border: solid #0D8200 .15em;
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
}

div:before{    
    content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);        
    background-repeat: space;    
}
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/mo7c1swt/3/

Comment: You are over complicating the answer and rendering poor pre-IE 8 compatability.

Comment: @Fearium:  OP did not mention any cross browser version compatibility in the question. Plus there would always be restrictions if you are looking for old version support.

Comment: He's looking for a solution for what he's using, not a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing "" on arg -  should be background-image: url("paper.gif");

Comment: url('file.jpg'), url(file.jpg), and url("file.jpg") should all work.